# performance loss in scala.jdk.CollectionConverters

Tags: scala, scala-collections

I am trying to use the cartesianProduct functionality from guava in a scala program.
https://guava.dev/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Sets.html#cartesianProduct(java.util.List)

The function cartesianProduct itself is lightning fast, but I seem to be losing a lot of time in conversions between Java and Scala collections.

For example, if the following code(though not a decent benchmark attempt) is run **with the two commented lines enabled**, there is a 700 fold increase of time on my laptop(~45 millis shoots upto ~35000 millis)

What could I be doing better?

```
import org.scalatest.BeforeAndAfter
import org.scalatest.diagrams.Diagrams
import org.scalatest.funspec.AnyFunSpecLike
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers

class CartesianProductTestStackOverFlow extends AnyFunSpecLike with Matchers with Diagrams with BeforeAndAfter {

  describe("CartesianProductPerformanceTest") {

    it("cartesian product perf test") {
      val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()

      import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableSet
      import com.google.common.collect.Sets._
      import scala.jdk.CollectionConverters._

      val cartProd//: Set[Seq[Int]]  //UNCOMMENT TO SEE PERFORMANCE DROP
      = cartesianProduct(ImmutableSet.copyOf((1 to 1000).asJava),
        ImmutableSet.copyOf((1 to 100).asJava),
        ImmutableSet.copyOf((1 to 100).asJava)
      ).asScala
        //.map(javaList => javaList.asScala.toSeq).toSet //UNCOMMENT TO SEE PERFORMANCE DROP
      assert(
        cartProd
          .size == 10000000
      )
      val totalTimeTaken = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
      println(s"cartesianProductTailRec : Total time taken (millis) $totalTimeTaken")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: First, that is not a proper way to benchmark. Second, I do not see any problem with the collection conversions, but if I uncomment the other lines you are adding extra steps; a `map` and many `toSeq` & `toSet` which all are **O(N)**, so it is not weird to see that big drop of execution time. Third, have you considered just using `flatMap`? And since this will produce a big collection, have you considered using **lazy** data structures?

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply.   So the ```toSeq``` and ```toSet``` are to get back immutability. Agreed they (could) be order N, however removing them still brings the time to the order of 10000 millis with the undesirable effect of having mutable data-structures around. I'm trying but failing to see the use case for a ```flatmap``` here, how would that help the performance if you don't mind elaborating? I suspect the ```.scala``` are proving O(N) as well, which is something I did not expect.

Comment: `asScala` should be instant. I mean, I believe a cartesian product is just the same as `seq1.flatMap(x => seq2.map(y => (x, y)))` and if both **seq1** and **seq2** are `Iterators`, `Views` or `LazyLists` then it will not compute anything until needed, which may be good enough.

Comment: Ah yeah, so the problem that use case of ```flatmap``` would be that the number of Sets to use as the basis for the cartesian product is not 2 or any number fixed at compile time. The argument Sets would come injected at runtime.

Comment: You also mentioned this is not a proper way to benchmark. I concede that, I was trying to write something quick and dirty to see how it plays out. Would you however say that I am completely off the mark there. This little test does seem repeatable in its results.

Comment: I mean, I believe you that this is slower, it is just to remember people that printing the time millis difference is not a benchmark. Anyways, `asScala` and `asJava` are just wrappers, they do not copy data, so they are instant. But maybe, the slowdown also comes from the way `cartesianProduct` is implemented? Maybe it expects an **O(1)** access by index which the wrapper doesn't provide?

Comment: "Maybe it expects an O(1) access by index which the wrapper doesn't provide?" - seems unlikely because across the two scenarios(fast and slow), I did not change the input to the function ,right?

Comment: The `map` also creates a new `Set` of 10000000 elements, which might not be a very cheap operation even without the extra `toSeq` and `toSet`. And perhaps part of the increased runtime could also be caused by increased GC activity.